# how to solve this mongo compass error of connection string?

Tags: database, mongodb, compass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4I3M.png)

I am sure that username, pass, and DB name is correct,

but I am using office restricted wifi, is this is because of restricted wifi???

Answer (score 0):

`queryTXT ESERVFAIL` indicates a DNS error when attempting to lookup the TXT record for the cluser.

Try using the `mongodb://` connection string (you might have to tell Atlas that you are using a client older than 3.6).